# link with an iframe target not working in IE9

Tags: html

Having a problem with a page on our intranet that works fine on IE7,8 and FF but does not work in IE9.

We have a page with a set of links and an iframe containing an SSRS report, on clicking the individual links it should change the contents of the iframe to the href of the link by setting the target attribute to the name of the iframe. This is not working on IE9 the links do not change the content of the iframe.

Should this work in IE9 or do I need to find an alternative way of getting it to work?

links

```
<li><a id="lnkAllMatchtech" href="http://SSRSserver/report1" target="graph">Report 1</a></li>
<li><a id="HyperLink5" href="http://SSRSserver/report2" target="graph">Report 2</a></li>
<li><a id="HyperLink1" href="http://SSRSserver/report3" target="graph">Report 3</a></li>
```

iframe

```
<iframe src="http://SSRSserver/report1" name="graph" height="260" width="340" />
```

UPDATE : Looks like it might be something to do with the querystring parameters passed to the SSRS report.

We have a qs like

```
?%2fGeneris+Report+Server%2fIntranetStats&Sector=Barclay+Meade&rs%3aParameterLanguage=&rc%3aParameters=Collapsed&rc%3aToolbar=False
```

If I remove all the &rs and &rc parameters it works, although it then displays toolbars and parameter boxes which I don't want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this wasted a large part of my day, unable to find a way around the parameter issue I came across another solution that was suggested on the net.

Switched my iframe for a object tag and added this little jquery snippet to change the contents of the object tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("a").click(function() {

                $("#graph").attr('data', this.href);
                return false;
            });

        });
</script>


  <object id="graph" name="graph" type="text/html" data="http://SSRSServer/report1"
                    height="260" width="340" ></object>
```